# how to reduce paddings between selects in bootstrap

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

`.class-group` has some padding left and right, how can i reduce it, i tried to add zero padding's to left and right, but this didn't work. How can i do it properly? I need to implement this for bootstrap 3.7

```css
.selection-form > div {
    margin: auto;
}


.center {
    margin: 0 auto;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!DOCTYPE html>

    <div class="container">
   
         <section class="filter-appartment">
                 
            <div class="col-md-12">

               <form class="form-inline selection-form">

                     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                       <select id="" class="form-control">
                         <option>Projects</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                       <select id="" class="form-control">
                         <option>Sale</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group col-md-2" > 
                       <select id="" class="form-control">
                         <option>Price</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>

                     <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                       <select id="" class="form-control">
                         <option>Disabled select</option>
                       </select>
                     </div>

                 </form>

            </div>
                    
           </section>   
      </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/9ogjny53/4/

Answer (score 1):

Add `p-0` class on the element from which you want to remove the padding.

Learn here:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/spacing/

See the updated [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9ogjny53/7/)

Comment: Thanks לבני מלכה :)

Comment: unfortunately i'm using bootstrap 3.7 and i don't see actually that padding became smaller

Comment: But in your fiddle you are using bootstrap 4 ! So i answered according. Please change your question accordingly. and create a class p-0 with the following style .p-0 {
    padding: 0!important;
}